# Passar $scope.variavel para um um javascript tageado na home

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Como passar conteúdo dentro do config para variáveis globais:

```
//meu config
app.run(function(editableOptions, $rootScope, $filter) {
        editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; // bootstrap3 theme. Can be also 'bs2', 'default'
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, current, pre) {
            var c = current.$$route.originalPath.length;
           $rootScope.action = current.$$route.originalPath;
        });
    });
```

Na view quero redefinir uma variável dentro do HTML, é possível? No exemplo abaixo não funciona:

```
<script>
var action = '{{action}}';
</script>
```

Tentei isso:

```
  //meu config
    app.run(function(editableOptions, $rootScope, $filter) {
            editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; // bootstrap3 theme. Can be also 'bs2', 'default'
            $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, current, pre) {
                var c = current.$$route.originalPath.length;
               $rootScope.action = '<script> var action = "'+current.$$route.originalPath+'";</script>';
            });
        });

{{action}}
```

Também não funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a variável window como global, só tem que prestar atenção quando ela é alterada

No Javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
window.test1 = 10;
window.test2;

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope',
  function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.varA = test1;
    window.test2 = 'shared with window';
  }]
);

function myFunction() {
  alert(test2);
}
```

No Html

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

 {{varA}}

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/toninho09/zjbohcve/2/